# average with all blank values error handling

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I have a looping macro calculating averages of three values. In rare cases all three values might be blank, so I need the macro to then leave the cell where the average is printed blank, and continue with the next iteration of the loop.

I haven't done error handling before, so not sure the best way to go abut it. Here is my code:

```
Sub sumavg()
        Dim i As Long, j As Long
        With Worksheets("datasummary")
            For i = 1 To .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row Step 5
                For j = 1 To 6
                    With .Rows(i + 2)
                        .Columns(19 + j).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(.Columns(j), .Columns(j + 5), .Columns(j + 10))
                    End With
                    With .Rows(i + 3)
                        .Columns(19 + j).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(.Columns(j), .Columns(j + 5), .Columns(j + 10))
                    End With
                Next
            Next

        End With
    End Sub
```

[image: Here is a screenshot of the data]

Comment: Try `On Error Resume Next`

Comment: @nightcrawler23 I have considered that. Just worried the results might be unpredictable seeing as the error isn't actually handled. And is that line written at the top of the macro, or can it be written in the loop?

Comment: @shecodes, you are right trying to avoid `On Error Resume Next` solution , since it's a "blind" one covering the one error you already know about (and that's fine) along with other possible errors you don't know about (and that's not good). The best is _catch_ the error and treat it appropriately, as a _real_ error handling could allow you to or using `Application`'s object functions capability of wrapping possible errors in the returned value (see my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call `Application` object's `Average()` function and check its result against being an error:

```
Sub sumavg()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim res As Variant '<--| this will store the result of Application.Average() function

    With Worksheets("datasummary")
        For i = 1 To .Range("A" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).row Step 5
            For j = 1 To 6
                With .Rows(i + 2)
                    res = Application.Average(.Columns(j), .Columns(j + 5), .Columns(j + 10))
                    If Not IsError(res) Then .Columns(19 + j).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(.Columns(j), .Columns(j + 5), .Columns(j + 10))
                End With
                With .Rows(i + 3)
                    res = Application.Average(.Columns(j), .Columns(j + 5), .Columns(j + 10))
                    If Not IsError(res) Then .Columns(19 + j).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(.Columns(j), .Columns(j + 5), .Columns(j + 10))
                End With
            Next
        Next

    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `On Error Resume Next` or simply add zeros to the values you are averaging.

```
Sub sumavg()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        For i = 1 To .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row Step 5
            For j = 1 To 6
                With .Rows(i + 2)
                    .Columns(19 + j).Value = WorksheetFunction.Average(.Columns(j) + 0, .Columns(j + 5) + 0, .Columns(j + 10) + 0)
                End With
                With .Rows(i + 3)
                    .Columns(19 + j).Value = WorksheetFunction.Average(.Columns(j) + 0, .Columns(j + 5) + 0, .Columns(j + 10) + 0)
                End With
            Next
        Next

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't add 0's because I need to be able to differentiate between trials that actually have a 0 value, and trials that need to be excluded (i.e. blank). I will try resume next.

Comment: the `On Error Resume Next` appears to be working fine.

Comment: Great! BTW `On Error Resume Next` should go inside the subroutine. for your case it can be right after the `Sub sumavg()`

Comment: I've put it  after `For j = 1 to 6`. My reasoning was that that might minimise any undesired behaviour. Not sure if that's really how it works, haha.

Comment: the `On Error resume Next` solution should be considered an option only when no other "normal" solutions are in reach.